# Populating dynamic form row from generated list PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making something for a stocktake.

I have a form that generates with 4 fields. item_code, item_name, packing, quantity

```
<form action="goods.php" method="post">
<table>
<!-- Headers -->
<tr>
<td><b>Item Code</b></td>
<td><b>Description</b></td>
<td><b>Packing</b></td>
<td><b>Quantity</b></td>
</tr>

<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++) {
?>
<tr>
<td>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="item_code[<?php echo $i; ?>]" SIZE="6" VALUE="
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["item_code"][($i)])) {
echo $_POST["item_code"][($i)]; 
}
?>"></td>
<td><?php 
if (!empty($_POST["item_code"][($i)])) {
$result = FetchData($_POST["item_code"][($i)]);
echo $result['category'];
}
?>
</td>
<td>
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST["item_code"][($i)])) {
echo $result['item_name'];
}
?></td>
<td>
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST["item_code"][($i)])) {
echo $result['packing'];
}
?></td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="quantity[<?php echo $i; ?>]" SIZE="5" VALUE="
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST["quantity"][($i)])) {
echo $_POST["quantity"][($i)]; 
} else {
echo "";
}
?>"></td>
```

A js function for the button

```
<script>
function fillForm(value) {
document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = value;
}
</script>
```

and a list that is generated with 3 fields. item_code, item_name, packing

```
<?php 
$dbh = dbh_get();

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM goods as goods(item_code, sort) order by human_sort(goods.item_code)'; 

  $v = array();
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
while (true) {
$r = $stmt->fetch();
if (is_bool($r)) break;

 print '
<tr>
    <td class="buttonL" id="<php ' . $r['item_code'] . ' ?>" onclick="fillForm()">' . $r['item_code'] . '</td>
    <td>' . $r['item_name'] . '</td>
    <td>' . $r['packing'] . '</td>
</tr>' . "\n";
}
dbh_free($dbh);
?>
    }
```

I want to put a button on each list row and when it's clicked it populates the first three fields in the form, leaving quantity to be filled out. Then when another is clicked it populates the next form row etc,. It's working fine manually entering from the list, but the list is nearly 5000 items so it's a hassle to keep searching then scrolling up and entering the values.

I don't see how to do this with PHP so I assume I need a javascript function, which is where I'm lost. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I think `jquery` might be a good library to use on your scenario.

Comment: @catzilla I can't use jquery, I need a js or php solution.